# JAVA: "error: unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown"

Tags: java, exception, throw

I am new to programming in JAVA and got stuck in code where I need to print the the exponential result of two non-negative numbers. In case if any of them is negative, I need to throw an exception, my code is as follows:`

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class MyCalculator {

    int power(int n, int p) {
        int result = 1;
        if (n < 0 || p < 0) {
            throw new Exception("n and p should be non-negative");
            else
        {
        while(p!=0)
            {
            result=result*n;
            p-=1;
        }
        return result;
    }
        }
    }

    class Solution {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            while (in.hasNextInt()) {
                int n = in.nextInt();
                int p = in.nextInt();
                MyCalculator my_calculator = new MyCalculator();
                try {
                    System.out.println(my_calculator.power(n, p));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting the above written error IE:

```
error: unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

I needed a conceptual understanding of what actually is causing this error to occur.

Comment: Then Google "java exception". This is documented a zillion zillion times.

Comment: Your program will not even compile successfully.

Answer (score 3):

**First** You are putting else in the wrong place use this instead :

```
int result = 1;
if (n < 0 || p < 0) {
    throw new Exception("n and p should be non-negative");
} else {
^---------------------------------You have to close the if, then use else
    while (p != 0) {
        result = result * n;
        p -= 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Second** your method should be `throws Exception`

```
int power(int n, int p) throws Exception {
```

Comment: Good points, but I would leave out the catch example. Empty catch blocks are never a good idea, and throw followed by empty catch is super crazy.

Comment: thank you @GhostCat so can the `ex.printStackTrace();` do the trick, or what should i do to not let it empty?

Comment: It simply doesn't make sense to catch in this context. You could show how a user of pow() catches.

Comment: yes this is correct @GhostCat the OP already use `try {
                    System.out.println(my_calculator.power(n, p));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }` so he don't need to use this again in pow() method

Answer (score 2):

Exception classes like `Exception` derive from `Throwable`.
There are *checked* exceptions like the `Exception` and *unchecked* exceptions like `IllegalArgumentException`.

If you would have used the latter, the exception would be unvisible.

With a checked exception the compiler forces you to have a `throws ...` or to `catch` the exception.

Here an **IllegalArgumentException** would fit perfectly.

Comment: How to know whether an Exception is a checked or not in official documentations?

Comment: **Unchecked exceptions** extend RuntimeException, that extend Exception that extend Throwable. **Checked exceptions** extend Exception, not RuntimeException. And the rare **Errors** extend Throwable, not Exception. Seen at the top of the javadoc.